# Android Xamarin Form Targeting S+ (Version 31 and Above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I found many articles that discuss this issue but for me, no solution works.

First of all, the error on my Xamarin Form:

> Targeting S+ (Version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent...

What I have done is

1. Using `Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime` from version 2.7.0 to the latest 2.8.1.4 based on this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime/2.8.1.4) and still got the error
2. Find PendingIntent code on my project. I changed it to this

   ```
   var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
       ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable
       : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, pendingIntentFlags))
   ```

Still no luck. Any idea for this case? I have tried all the method I know.

Comment: Does this happen on a clean installation of the application?

Comment: What did you mean of clean installation?

Comment: Delete the app completely and install it. I vaguely remember that in update case it could cause some troubles.

Comment: Yes I have did. I have trying to clean -> delete bin obj folder -> restart vs but still no luck.

Comment: Did you use any other third party nuget package? Maybe there is an PendingIntent declared in the package. Please make sure all the packages you used support android api 31.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Unfortunately, I use many libraries in the project. How to know which project uses PendinIntent? I have search a whole project and only 1 PendingItent in my project. I have changed it and commenting out but still no luck.

Comment: It seems there is no way can find it easily. You need to check every nuget package by yourself.